# How to know library variable names for CMakeLists?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake

When using CMakeLists to compile an OpenGL project, I have the following line to link glut and gl:

```
target_link_libraries(my_exe ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES})
```

I looked up how to link glut and gl with CMake so I saw that I could use ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} and ${GLUT_LIBRARIES}. But how would I know the variables to use otherwise? I am used to just doing ${THELIBRARY_LIBRARES}, but in the case of gl, it changed to adding that "*gl*" into the variable name. How would I know that without googling it (for any library I want to use)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables are obtained via `find_package(XXX)` calls.

Such calls are redirected, depended from the library, either to `FindXXX.cmake` script (shipped with CMake or contained in the project which uses it) or to `XXXConfig.cmake` script (shipped with the library itself).

So, for determine meaningful variable's names you need to consult appropriate script. Usually, interface of the script (input-output variables) is described **in comments at the beginning of the script**.

Documentation for `FindXXX.cmake` scripts shipped with CMake may be read in [CMake documentation pages about modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-modules.7.html).

Comment: Thanks! (Accepting this one because it was first...) Where is FindXXX.cmake that is shipped with CMake?

Answer (score 9):

Besides consulting the find module's documentation, you could also use CMake's [`VARIABLES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html) property to give you the variables that were defined by your [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) call.

For an example the following code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(FindPackageVars)

get_directory_property(_vars_before VARIABLES)
find_package(OpenGL)
get_directory_property(_vars VARIABLES)

list(REMOVE_ITEM _vars _vars_before ${_vars_before})
foreach(_var IN LISTS _vars)
    message(STATUS "${_var} = ${${_var}}")
endforeach()
```

Outputs on my machine:

```sh
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_OpenGL = [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so][/usr/include][v()]
-- OPENGL_FOUND = TRUE
-- OPENGL_GLU_FOUND = YES
-- OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include
-- OPENGL_INCLUDE_PATH = /usr/include
-- OPENGL_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- OPENGL_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- OPENGL_XMESA_FOUND = NO
-- OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
-- OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR = OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It is dependent on the find-module for the library.

[See here.](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)

Under **Writing find modules** you see that variables are set in the module. When checking the `FindOpenGL.cmake` module in your CMake-Modules directory you will see the name of the variable.

Comment: Where is the CMake-Modules directory located? (Ubuntu 16.04) I cannot find it under /usr/lib/cmake.

Comment: @Sterling According to the article it is located under __/usr/share/cmake/Modules__. I am using CLion, for my installation it was located in the CLion directory, maybe yours is also bundled with the IDE (in case you are using one).

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah I found mine in /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules. Thanks!!